# Error when using cql3 with Astyanax

Tags: astyanax, cql3

I was trying to run a simple Cql3 query with Astyanax and I keep on getting an error.

The aim is to create a simple table via Astyanax using cql3.

```
public class SomeTest {

private AstyanaxContext<Keyspace> astyanaxContext;
private Keyspace keyspace;

private static String CREATE_TABLE_QUERY = "CREATE TABLE top_items (\n" +
        "  categoryName varchar,\n" +
        "  type varchar,\n" +
        "  baseItemId int,\n" +
        "  margin float,\n" +
        "  ds timestamp,\n" +
        "  PRIMARY KEY (categoryName, ds)\n" +
        ");";

@Before
public void setUp() {
    try {
        this.astyanaxContext = new AstyanaxContext.Builder()
                .forCluster("ClusterName")
                .forKeyspace("new_examples")
                .withAstyanaxConfiguration(new AstyanaxConfigurationImpl().setDiscoveryType(NodeDiscoveryType.NONE).setCqlVersion("3.0.0"))
                .withConnectionPoolConfiguration(
                        new ConnectionPoolConfigurationImpl("MyConnectionPool").setMaxConnsPerHost(1).setPort(9160)
                                .setSeeds("localhost:9160")).withConnectionPoolMonitor(new CountingConnectionPoolMonitor())
                .buildKeyspace(ThriftFamilyFactory.getInstance());

        this.astyanaxContext.start();
        this.keyspace = this.astyanaxContext.getEntity();
        // Using simple strategy
        keyspace.createKeyspace(ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
                .put("strategy_options", ImmutableMap.<String, Object>builder()
                        .put("replication_factor", "1")
                        .build())
                .put("strategy_class",     "SimpleStrategy")
                .build()
        );

        // test the connection
        this.keyspace.describeKeyspace();
    } catch (Throwable e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Failed to prepare CassandraBolt", e);
    }
}

@Test
public void testWrite() throws ConnectionException {
    ColumnFamily<String, String> CQL3_CF = ColumnFamily.newColumnFamily(
            "Cql3CF",
            StringSerializer.get(),
            StringSerializer.get());

    OperationResult<CqlResult<String, String>> result;
    result = keyspace
            .prepareQuery(CQL3_CF)
            .withCql(CREATE_TABLE_QUERY)
            .execute();
}
}
```

When I run the test I get this stack trace

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.thrift.meta_data.FieldValueMetaData.<init>(BZ)V
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$execute_cql_query_args.<clinit>(Cassandra.java:32588)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.send_execute_cql_query(Cassandra.java:1393)
at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.execute_cql_query(Cassandra.java:1387)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$6$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:699)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$6$1.internalExecute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:696)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:55)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.AbstractOperationImpl.execute(AbstractOperationImpl.java:27)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl$1.execute(ThriftSyncConnectionFactoryImpl.java:136)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.tryOperation(AbstractExecuteWithFailoverImpl.java:69)
at com.netflix.astyanax.connectionpool.impl.AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.executeWithFailover(AbstractHostPartitionConnectionPool.java:248)
at com.netflix.astyanax.thrift.ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl$6.execute(ThriftColumnFamilyQueryImpl.java:694)
at storage.cassandra.daos.SomeTest.testWrite(SomeTest.java:76)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:76)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:195)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:63)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:120)
```

I'm using "com.netflix.astyanax" % "astyanax" % "1.56.18" .

Please help.

Comment: You may try to use a newer version. Latest one is 1.56.23. I'm using this one without having any issue.

Comment: 156.23 works with Cassandra 1.2 but is not working with Cassandra 1.2.1

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Astyanax is not properly supporting Cassandra 1.2 or 1.2.1 (not even 1.56.24, released 7 days ago...). You may try java-driver instead. It is not yet released but it works fine, as far as I have tested.
https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

Comment: How did you get it to work? I have issues with the driver...I have this Cassandra Initializer: https://gist.github.com/shehaaz/5279566 and if I even try to initiate it using new Cassandra(); It breaks. 
Does it have to do with the ProtocolOptions having the default Port: 9042. In my machine it is 9160. And also why doesn't the driver let me input my own Port? Or maybe I am doing everything complete wrong. Thank you @bitover

Comment: in order to use port 9042 you have to enable native transport in cassandra.yaml

Comment: Thanks! I just set the start_native_transport: true...I can see "Starting listening for CQL clients on /127.0.0.1:9042..." in the server...but the driver from the gist I posted is still giving a "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cassandra/transport/FrameCompressor" for the Cluster.java:230 Do you have a working version I can look at? Thanks @bitlover

Comment: You have to add dependency on cassandra-all package on your pom.xml, if you are using Maven or equivalent in ant/grails/sbt

Comment: I am not using Maven unfortunately or ant in my project...but I built the java-driver using maven and then imported the external library...I thought it was simple...it's weird the code is not complaining...it's a runtime error

Comment: @bitlover It works!!! I figured maven out!!! I just used the pom files from the stress example...and changed the artificial name of the root! :)